# How can I replace with more values in a text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, replace

I have an (AngularJS) project where I will replace some tags in a text. By example:

```
{tag1} => one
{tag2} => two
{tag3} => three
```

With the JavaScript replace function can I replace one value:

```
text.replace('{tag1}', 'one');
```

But I have a list of 25 tags. I would like to make an object with the tags and replacements. By example:

```
var tags = {"{tag1}":"one", "{tag2}":"two", "{tag3}":"three"};
text.replace(tags);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add real example with complete string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use RegEx.

```
str.replace(/{[^{}]+}/g, m => tags[m] || m);
```

The function `m => tags[m] || m` is using ES6 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax.
Equivalent code in ES5:

```
function(m) {
    return tags[m] || m;
}
```

If the matched string(*tag*) is found in the object, then the value of that tag is returned. If not then the matched string itself is returned.

**RegEx Explanation:**

1. `{`: Match `{` literal
2. `[^{}]+`: Match one or more characters except `{` and `}`
3. `}`: Match `}` literal
4. `g`: Global flag

```js
var str = 'Hello {tag1}, I\'m {tag2}. Where is {tag3}. - {tag1} {NoTag}';

var tags = {
    "{tag1}": "one",
    "{tag2}": "two",
    "{tag3}": "three"
};

str = str.replace(/{[^{}]+}/g, m => tags[m] || m);

console.log(str);
document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

I'll also suggest to use ES6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
var tag1 = 'one',
    tag2 = 'two',
    tag3 = 'three';

var str = `Hello ${tag1}, I\'m ${tag2}. Where is ${tag3}.`;
```

```js
var tag1 = 'one',
    tag2 = 'two',
    tag3 = 'three';

var str = `Hello ${tag1}, I\'m ${tag2}. Where is ${tag3}.`;

document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: It works brilliant! I still have one problem. I have this scope:
          `$scope.tags = {
            "{tag1}": "one",
            "{tag2}": "two"
          }`
How can i add items to this scope? It don't works by me with the javascript push function.

Comment: @JanvanRijswijk You can't use `push` on object. You can use `$scope.tags['{tag3}'] = 'Three';` to add new item in the `tags` object.

Answer (score 3):

You can just loop over the tags object:

```
var tags = {"{tag1}":"one", "{tag2}":"two", "{tag3}":"three"};
for(var key in tags)
    text.replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), tags[key]);
```

Comment: .. but this smells like an XSS exploit waiting to happen, so be careful to properly escape any input to make sure it can't be used to inject malicious HTML or javascript.

Comment: True, but you can't make those assumptions without seeing the rest of his code, this is just an exact answer to his question

Comment: I'm not criticising your answer, I'm simply providing a warning to the OP :)

Answer (score -1):

You could use the '/g' regexp suffix to replace all occurrences, till the end of the text, like this:

```
text.replace(new RegExp('{tag1}', "g"), 'one');
```

More about Javascript string replace can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144783/2869791).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it only handles one "tag" - the OP wants to pass in an object with multiple tags.